# Configuring Webpack on Angular 4 with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, npm, build, webpack-2

In my application, I want to use SASS and a few front-end libraries that are loaded using NPM. To setup the bundling, I need to use a tool like Webpack.

At first, I tried to find the Webpack config file that Angular-CLI uses. Later, I discovered that Angular-CLI wants you to be free from configuration. But my problem is that I need to configure SASS transpiling, etc before I can run my application, and manually running a handful of commands is really not a good idea. I usually use `ng serve` which as the name implies, lets me test my application + watches for changes and applies changes. What I want to do is, run a handful of scripts that execute when a change is detected in this process. How would I go about this problem?

**Update:**

Compiling SASS was one of the things I had to solve, which has been solved. I also want to run Autoprefixer and package some node_modules on the build. What would be the best way?

Comment: `ng new --style scss` would use SASS right out of the box. You can also reconfigure in `.angular-cli.json` at any time. if you want your own webpack config then `ng eject` at any time. All in the docs.

Comment: @NeilLunn would you link me to this particular thing? I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Maybe try using gulp ? AngularJS did that back in the time, so maybe you could use gulp to run your tasks, and copy what `ng serve` does

Comment: If your only probleme is SASS as @Neil suggested, you can just open the `angular-cli.json` file and change the extension, he will compile it automatically (scss, less ...)

Comment: @trichetriche not sure why you would want gulp when webpack already does most of what you would roll

Comment: Because I understood that he wanted to have a custom behavior on `ng serve`, but if he justs want to have SASS enabled (what I didn't understand it seems), your solution (and second mine) are both easier

Comment: Alright, so lets say I already have the application setup? What would I do to update the Angular-CLI to compile SASS for me. Another thing I want to run is a library that updates vendor prefixes for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after hours of searching through the documentations, googling, etc., I was able to solve every single problem listed above. It was simple.

**Using CSS Preprocessors**

Like @NeilLunn suggested, to use SCSS or any other preprocessor, you can use:

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss" // or another pre-processor, or plain css itself.
}
```

More information about using other pre-processor's can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors

**Loading CSS/JS dependencies in the project**

This one was pretty straightforward. You can see an example of how [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) can be loaded for example [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap).

**Using Autoprefixer**

This was the most painful one to find about, but I finally found it. Turns out, all you have to do is [this right here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-autoprefixer) and that actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

Angular cli suppots sass and less right out of the box. You can configure with `--style` to [`ng new`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new) or simply edit the `.angular-cli.json`

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",  // or sass; both are accepted
}
```

If you want to see full options, just list the help:

```
ng help
```

Of course if you want **full** control, you can get a standard webpack configuration by running [ng eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject):

```
ng eject
```

At any time.

Comment: Great! I'll test that right away. One more thing: once the SASS is compiled to CSS, I want to run something like Autoprefixer on it.

Another thing I want to do is, I want to load some front-end libraries. Would I be able to configure them as well?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf As noted, you can customize things further by running `ng eject` and then alter the webpack configuration manually. This also adds sass and less dependencies etc to your project and sets up scripts in `package.json`

Comment: It broke my `ng serve`

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Once you `ng eject` you use `npm run serve`. Look at "scripts" in the `package.json`. Point is once you do that, it's no longer a cli project and you are doing it all yourself.

Comment: I kinda want cli too. What should I do? @NeilLunn

Comment: @HassanAlthaf It's your choice really. As stated, most things are just going to work out of the box. If you **need** to configure custom loaders for webpack, then you no longer have a cli project. What "I do" is use the cli to get basic scaffolding and layout done, then when I want to play with other things I do `ng eject` and tune things. To "me" it sounds like you want to "play" prematurely, and maybe you should get your app going first, then add fancy loaders and things.

Comment: I want to load Bootstrap 3 and setup Autoprefixer. That's all I need to do now. What's the best way?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf It's your option what **you** do. It's not up to "me". I can only tell you about the things you missed and were not aware of. Job done.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Yes it is the only way as the angular CLI team didn't want to expose the webpack config by default and for god's sake accept NeilLunn answer as he gave you everything you need to know to solve the issue.

Comment: @HamedBaatour That's for me to decide whether to accept the answer or not. I'd rather wait to see if I could get another answer if in case there are better ways of doing things.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf How much plainer can we make it? You cannot access the webpack configuration used in a cli project. You can either accept what the cli does, or move to a webpack configuration. You can either roll your own webpack config, or have the cli set up some "useful" defaults. It's just a tool to get you started, and will not do everything for you. That is a design point. More than enough info is already given

Comment: @HassanAlthaf there is no better way and you can wait here forever I am just trying to say that this is all we have for the moment and I even asked Mike Brocchi (angular CLI team member) on the angular air show in the live chat and he said it's a work in progress and for now we can't expose the web pack config by default anyways wish you luck in your issue!

Comment: @NeilLunn Look at my answer.

Comment: @HamedBaatour Didn't I tell you there'd be a better way?